# "Is seen before" column for another column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider following data frame:

```
   a
0  1
1  1
2  2
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  4
```

Is there a convenient way (without iterating rows) to create a column that represent "is seen before" for every value of column `a`.
For example desired output for the example is (0 represent not seen before, 1 represent seen before):

```
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
```

If this is possible, is there a way to enhance it with counts of previous occurrences and not just binary indicator?

Comment: Following on from the answer, then possibly a grouped `.cumsum()` function for the running counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should just be `.duplicated()` ([see documentation](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pandas+duplicated&ia=web)). Then if you want to cast it to an integer for 0's and 1's instead of `False` and `True` you can use `.astype(int)` on the output:

From `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df.duplicated(subset="a").astype(int)
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
dtype: int32
```

From `pd.Series`:

```
df["a"].duplicated().astype(int)
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

This will mark the first time a value is "seen" as `False`, and all subsequent values that have already been "seen" as `True`. Coercing it to an `int` datatype via `astype` will change `False -> 0` and `True -> 1`

Answer (score 2):

Use assign and duplicated:

```
df.assign(seenbefore = lambda x: x.a.duplicated().astype(int))
```